# A Storm of Swords: Why don't the unsullied attack Jhogo when Dany orders them to kill people with whips?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In *A Storm of Swords* Chapter 27, Danaerys orders her new Unsullied to

> Slay the Good Masters, slay the soldiers, slay every man who wears a tokar or holds a whip, but harm no child under twelve, and strike the chains off every slave you see.

The bloodrider Jhogo is there with his whip. In the same chapter, he uses his whip for defence:

> One man kept his saddle long enough to draw a sword, but Jhogo's whip coiled about his neck and cut off his shout

My question is, **why didn't the Unsullied attack Jhogo too**? Answers from the books only please.

Comment: Maybe they could make a distinction between a slave whip and a whip intended for stock control or as a weapon. .. Actually, it just occurred to me that the Dothraki dealt in slaves rather than herds, so to them slaves were 'stock'.  so that theory isn't very convincing.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I thought the same to begin with, thinking on the lines of "maybe the unsullied know the difference between a slaver & Dany's entourage?", but the unsullied haven't been 'introduced' to Jhogo. As far as I can tell, he is just a guy with a whip near the new boss from the point of view from the Unsullied.

Comment: Because they intuitively understood that when she said "wears a tokar or holds a whip," she meant "is one of the people who run things here and oppress everyone."  They're not Amelia Bedelia; and they're not actually robots killing people with whip == 1 in hand.

Comment: @gowenfawr - that isn't true. They've been trained to be utterly obedient, e.g. they're given a puppy to raise then kill, they are ordered to kill a slave child in front of the mother as part of their training, when Dany is shown them in formation the slaver says that they will stand there until ordered to move or until all of the unsullied die. They are trained relentlessly - running all day, climbing mountains at night etc. and if they fail any part of training they are culled immediately. All this speaks to them having given up independent thought a long time ago. That's why I asked :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The unsullied had seen Jhogo with Danaerys, when she had gone to inspect the unsullied.

> “Ask her if she wishes to view our fighting pits,” Kraznys added. “Douquor’s Pit has a fine folly scheduled for the evening. A bear and three small boys. One boy will be rolled in honey, one in blood, and one in rotting fish, and she may wager on which the bear will eat first.”
>
> Tap tap tap, Dany heard. Arstan Whitebeard’s face was still, but his staff beat out his rage. Tap tap tap. She made herself smile. “I have my own bear on Balerion,” she told the translator, “and he may well eat me if I do not return to him.”
>
> “See,” said Kraznys when her words were translated. “It is not the woman who decides, it is this man she runs to. As ever!”
>
> “Thank the Good Master for his patient kindness,” Dany said, “and tell him that I will think on all I learned here.” She gave her arm to Arstan Whitebeard, to lead her back across the plaza to her litter. **Aggo and Jhogo fell in to either side of them**, walking with the bowlegged swagger all the horselords affected when forced to dismount and stride the earth like common mortals.
>
> <sub><sup>*A Storm of Swords, Chapter 23, Danaerys*</sup></sub>

Comment: Good spot. When I was reviewing the text for an answer myself, I was so caught up in finding something like Dany saying "... except this guy" in chapter 27 that I missed this

Comment: @Bad_Bishop I tired doing the same and finally decided to look for Jhogo's name in the previous Danaerys's POV chapter. I couldn't believe GRRM had done a mistake!